# foreach loop in view while using a viewmodel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view

I am trying to get this foreach to loop over my CustomerVlan model.
but I have no idea how to do this while my view is using a ViewModel.
This is my code

my Controller

```
public List<Customervlan> cvlans = new List<Customervlan>();
public List<Connection> conn = new List<Connection>();

public IActionResult Create()
        {

            
            List<object> CvlanDB = new List<object>(_db.CustomerVlans);

            CvlanDB.Count();

            var VLANDDisnull = from myobject in _db.CustomerVlans
                          where myobject.DisconnectionDate == null
                          select myobject;
            

            ViewData["Customercode"] = new SelectList(_db.Customers, "Id", "CompanyName");
            ViewData["Customervlancode"] = new SelectList(VLANDDisnull.ToArray(), "Id", "CompanyName");
            ViewData["Switchcode"] = new SelectList(_db.Switchzs, "Id", "SwitchName");

            ConnVlanDron CV = new ConnVlanDron();
            
            CV.CustomerVlan = cvlans;
            CV.Connection = conn;

            return View(CV);
        }
```

The code in my view is throwing 2 errors:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  CS0230  Type and identifier are both required in a foreach statement        C:\Users\athen\source\repos\athenixz\AirportSit\AirportSit\Views\Connection\Create.cshtml   5

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  CS1579  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Customervlan' because 'Customervlan' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'      C:\Users\athen\source\repos\athenixz\AirportSit\AirportSit\Views\Connection\Create.cshtml   5

```
@using AirportSit.ViewModels

@model ConnVlanDron

@foreach(Azure in Model.CustomerVlan){}

<form method="post">
    <div class="border p-3 mt-4">
        <div class="row pb-2">
            <h2 class="text-primary">Create Connection</h2>
            <hr />
        </div>
        @*<div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>*@
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Connection.SwitchPortNumber"></label>
            <input asp-for="Connection.SwitchPortNumber" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Connection.SwitchPortNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
...
```

the viewmodel does work though just not the @foreach

Edit
i added var to my foreach loop
which removed an error now i get this.
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  CS1579  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Customervlan' because 'Customervlan' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'      C:\Users\athen\source\repos\athenixz\AirportSit\AirportSit\Views\Connection\Create.cshtml   5

[image]

ViewModel

```
using AirportSit.Models;

namespace AirportSit.ViewModels
{
    public class ConnVlanDron
    {
        public Connection Connection { get; set; }

        public Customervlan CustomerVlan { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: _foreach( type variable in collection of type)_ what is the variable or the type here: _@foreach(Azure in Model.CustomerVlan)_?

Comment: @Steve I just updated my question I added var to my foreach which did remove one of my errors but it just did not remove the GetEnumerator error

Comment: Could you add the definition for the class _ConnVlanDron_?

Comment: @Steve hello again i am quite new to this so i do not understand your awnser. How would i go about adding a definition for the class? I updated my question again i added my viewmodel code

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
first i went to my viewmodels and changed the models to list.

```
using AirportSit.Models;

namespace AirportSit.ViewModels
{
    public class ConnVlanDron
    {
        public List<Connection> Connection { get; set; }

        public List<Customervlan> CustomerVlan { get; set; }
        public Connection conn { get; set; }

    }
}
```

after changing them to list all my input asp-for got errors.
so i just decided to add connection again to my viewmodel without the list Infront.
Do not know if this is redundant in ASP.NET standards but eh at least it works now

```
public Connection conn { get; set; }
```